# jQuery hide bootstrap slide menu when clicked anywhere on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Made a Fiddle here:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/r94dq2e4/

I am using twitter bootstap version 3 with a slide in menu from the left when navbar toggle button is clicked.

This is the jQuery code I'm using:

```
// Nav
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    // Toggle classes in body for syncing sliding animation with other elements
    $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2')
        .on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            $('body').addClass('menu-slider');
        })
        .on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            $('body').addClass('in');
        })
        .on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            $('body').removeClass('menu-slider');
        })
        .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            $('body').removeClass('in');
        });

})(jQuery);
```

This works well and on first click of the navbar toggle button, the menu slides in, when clicked again, the menu slides out. I would like to enhance this functionality in such a way that the menu slides out when the user clicks anywhere on the page except for the menu itself.

This is my HTML for the menu:

Toggle navigation 
                                     
                                    
                                     
                                    Menu

```
                       <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">    
                           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="dropdown">   
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Treatments<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</span></a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">See the results</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Cost</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Information</a></li> 
                            </ul><!-- end navbar-nav -->
                        </div><!-- end navbar-collapse -->
                    </nav><!-- end navbar -->
```

I have started with the following jQuery code to achieve this. But I would need some help in where to go from here:

```
/* Nav click outside hide navbar */
    $(document).click(function(e){

    // Check if click was triggered on or within #menu_content
        if( $(e.target).closest("#navbar2").length > 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise
        // trigger your click function
         $('body').removeClass('menu-slider');
         $('body').removeClass('in');

    });
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a working version?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. Made a fiddle for the working version here: 

https://jsfiddle.net/r94dq2e4/

Comment: Check it, it doesn't really work. It's impossible to help without viewing the problem.

Comment: make the HTML preview viewport smaller so that it is less than 991px, then you will see the Menu button appear, clicking which will bring the menu. The menu is supposed to be shown only on screen sizes under 991px hence it doesnt appear on larger screens. Let me know if it works : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things that you need to check in order to see if you should close the menu:

1. The element is not the nav itself (`.nav`)
2. The element is not the nav container (`.navbar-cllapse`)
3. The element is not a child-element of the nav (`.parents('.nav')`)

```
if (!$(e.target).hasClass('navbar-collapse') && !$(e.target).hasClass('nav') && $(e.target).parents('.nav').length == 0) {
    $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2').removeClass('in');
}
```

You can try it in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r94dq2e4/1/

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the added explanation.